# Transform Map[String,Any] to a dataframe in Scala

Tags: dataframe, scala, dictionary, apache-spark

I have the following object of type `Map[String,Any]`:

```
d: Map[String,Any] = Map(count -> 1, results -> List(Map(A -> 1, C -> Hello, B -> Map(BA -> 0, BC -> 0)), Map(A -> 2, C -> Hi, B -> Map(BA -> 0, BC -> 0))), parameters -> Map(P1 -> 805, P2 -> 20230101))
```

I dont need most of these informations. I only need to extract results map list into a dataframe (ignoring the B object as it is a map). So the desired output would be:

```
+---------+----------------+
| A       |C               |
+---------+----------------+
|  1      |Hello           |
|  2      |Hi              |
+---------+----------------+
```

I tried:

```
val df = d
  .map( m => (m.get("A"),m.get("C")))
  .toDF("A", "C")
```

But I got

```
error: value get is not a member of Any
```

Comment: what's the type of  `d`?

Comment: d = res sorry I will edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try casting `.asInstanceOf[Seq[Map[String, Any]]]`, `.asInstanceOf[(Int, String)]`

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

val d: Map[String,Any] = Map(
  "count" -> 1, 
  "results" -> List(
    Map("A" -> 1, "C" -> "Hello", "B" -> Map("BA" -> 0, "BC" -> 0)), 
    Map("A" -> 2, "C" -> "Hi", "B" -> Map("BA" -> 0, "BC" -> 0))
  ), 
  "parameters" -> Map("P1" -> 805, "P2" -> 20230101)
)

val spark = SparkSession.builder
  .master("local")
  .appName("Spark app")
  .getOrCreate()

import spark.implicits._

val df = d("results")
  .asInstanceOf[Seq[Map[String, Any]]]
  .map(m => 
    (m("A"), m("C")).asInstanceOf[(Int, String)]
  )
  .toDF("A", "C")

df.show()

//+---+-----+
//|  A|    C|
//+---+-----+
//|  1|Hello|
//|  2|   Hi|
//+---+-----+
```