# What is the good type instance to put for a float value inside a map?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to cast values from a map into a dataframe as done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75462709/transform-mapstring-any-to-a-dataframe-in-scala).

I am having a problem as one of the columns I am extracting is a `double` sometimes and sometimes an `integer`.

This is what I done:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

val d: Map[String,Any] = Map(
  "count" -> 1, 
  "results" -> List(
    Map("A" -> 20, "C" -> "Hello", "B" -> Map("BA" -> 0, "BC" -> 0)), 
    Map("A" -> 1.52, "C" -> "Hi", "B" -> Map("BA" -> 0, "BC" -> 0))
  ), 
  "parameters" -> Map("P1" -> 805, "P2" -> 20230101)
)

val spark = SparkSession.builder
  .master("local")
  .appName("Spark app")
  .getOrCreate()

import spark.implicits._

val df = d("results")
  .asInstanceOf[Seq[Map[String, Any]]]
  .map(m => 
    (m("A"), m("C")).asInstanceOf[(Double, String)]
  )
  .toDF("A", "C")
```

And I am having:

```
RuntimeException: Error while encoding: java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.math.BigInt cannot be cast to java.lang.Double
```

I tried:

```
val df = d("results")
  .asInstanceOf[Seq[Map[String, Any]]]
  .map(m => 
    (m("A"), m("C")).asInstanceOf[(String, String)]
  )
  .toDF("A", "C")
```

But again:

```
RuntimeException: Error while encoding: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

How can I cast or put everything as `String` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Transform Map[String,Any] to a dataframe in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75462709/transform-mapstring-any-to-a-dataframe-in-scala)

You can replace casting `.asInstanceOf[Int]`/`.asInstanceOf[Double]` with pattern matching `match { case _: Int => ??? ; case _: Double => ??? }`

```
val df = d("results")
  .asInstanceOf[Seq[Map[String, Any]]]
  .map(m =>
    (
      m("A") match {
        case x: Double => x
        case x: Int    => x.toDouble
      },
      m("C").asInstanceOf[String]
    )
  )
  .toDF("A", "C")
```

Actually, under the hood pattern matching is implemented with `.isInstabceOf`, `.asInstanceOf` so this pattern matching is similar to

```
val x = m("A")
if (x.isInstanceOf[Double])   x.asInstanceOf[Double]
else if (x.isInstanceOf[Int]) x.asInstanceOf[Int].toDouble
else ???
```